# Prohibiting access on main website while allowing it through a subdomain?

Tags: php

I've been working on an application that requires users to log-in to view their material. Each user has their own subdomain which is locked by it's own accounts database. (I've done it this way for a reason, It's similar to how a forum free-host would work).

My problem is that if a user logs in using their subdomain..

```
Example --   sub.domain.com
```

and then moved to

```
Example -- sub2.domain.com
```

Everything is fine, they will be required to login again to access sub2.

However, let's say a user goes here to login (The actual directory of the subdomain)

```
Example -- domain.com/sub/
```

And then moves to

```
Example -- domain.com/sub2/
```

They will still be logged in and have access to all of the users information in **sub2**

How can I go about setting this up so I wont run into this problem, if anyone is curious I use $_SESSION for this login system.

Comment: A TLD (Top level domain), is just `.com` in your example/

Comment: About the problem: your rights system is flawed. Just make sure that users can only access their own database, whatever domain name they use. So keep record of which users belong to which account, and which account belongs to which database. If someone accesses a different url, they should go there as a visitor.

Comment: So, are you saying that when I create the session for the login I should create a session key that's for the subdomain? (Something I just thought of when reading your post) and then if the key doesn't match the subdomain you could terminate the login.

Comment: because, I have everything set up separately.  If the people at `example.domain.com` had an account named `bob123` that wouldn't stop the people at `exampletwo.domain.com` from having a user named `bob123` they are completely differnt databases, they are not meant to reference eachother.

Comment: `Example -- domain.com/sub/` - why is the same content accessible via a subdomain and a folder on the root domain? The "problem" is the path the session cookie is set to, but it's just an indicator of "bigger problems"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment that GolezTrol provided, I came up with this solution. This solution may have it's problems and if it does I would like to be informed about them. What I did was gave each client it's own Private-Key. (This key is randomly generated when their website is created and stored locally on the clients server. Clients do not have access to the files so this can't be downloaded or modified). I then store the private key in the session, and check the private key that is in the users session versus the private key of the client they are trying to view, if they are not the same it brings the user to the login page and clears their session. (This will log them out of their own dashboard as-well, but I'm planning on making it so the session dies when they leave the page anyway)

The only way someone could edit their session data to get access to another client would be by having the clients private-key, and considering they can't get that without logging in, in the first place, I doubt we have a problem.